# Prove that the determinant of the jacobian of $F$ is constantly zero given restrictions on $Im(f)$

Tags: analysis, functions, proof-verification, implicit-function-theorem

I need to prove that the jacobian of 
$f:\Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R$ is constantly zero

given that $Im(f)$ (the image of $f$) is contained in $S$,

where $S$ is the points of $\Bbb R^3$ where a function $g:\Bbb R^3\to \Bbb R$ is constantly zero

given that the gradient of $g$ is never zero for all $\Bbb R^3$

I've thought of using the theorem of the implicit function, but I'm really getting nowhere. Any help will be appreciated! 
Thanks in advance

Comment: There is a typo somewhere. Your $f$ goes from $\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}$ yet you say that the image of $f$ is in $S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that $f$ is in fact a function from $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ otherwise your condition doesn't make sense. You have that

$$g\circ f:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R} $$

is constantly zero by your assumption that $im(f) \subset S$. Now take the derivative of this function at any point $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and use the chain rule to obtain:

$$dg_{f(x)}\circ df_x=0. $$

Now you can use that $dg_{f(x)}\neq 0$ to deduce that $df_x$ doesn't have full rank and therefore $\det(df_x)=0$.

Comment: Thanks @maik !! very elegant :)